# Committing mysql query with python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having trouble committing an insert statement.

It seems that python can't call the db object and I do not understand why.

**Error:**

On line `self.db.commit()`

```
[-] ERROR:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

**Code:**

```
class Database(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = self.db_connect()

    def db_connect(self):
        try:
            self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host=MYSQL_HOST, 
                                    user=MYSQL_USER, 
                                    passwd=MYSQL_PWD, 
                                  db=MYSQL_DATABASE) 
            print '[+] Connected to {db} database'.format(db=MYSQL_DATABASE)
            self.cur = self.db.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print '[-] ERROR: ',e

    def add_email(self, email):
        try:            
            self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO User (email) VALUES (%s)', (email))           
            self.db.commit()
            print '[+] Added {email} to User(email) '.format(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            print '[-] ERROR: ',e
            print '[*] Rolling back'
            self.db.rollback()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `def db_connect` not return any thing. Means it returns `None`.

As per your code

```
def __init__(self):
    self.db = self.db_connect() # db_connect return None
```

set `self.db` as `None` and when you try to commit, it gives error.